# Looping over Array's values in Batch

Tags: arrays, batch-file, for-loop

I have a File_2 that contains lines as follow

```
A1,A2,A3,A4
B1,B2,B3,B4
```

In another File_1 I have multiple lines as follow:

```
X
Y
Z
```

What I Want is to have File_3 with all possible combinations:

```
A1;A2;X;A4
A1;A2;Y;A4
A1;A2;Z;A4
B1;B2;X;B4
B1;B2;Y;B4
B1;B2;Z;B4
```

I use a code that populate an array from File_1 then I try to combine it with File_2 to obtain the File_3:

```
SET /A i=0
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (File_1.txt) DO (
    SET /P Var[%i%]=%%a
    SET /A i=+1
)

SET /A Counter=0

FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1-7" %%a IN (File_2.txt) DO (
    IF %Counter% LEQ %i% (
        ECHO %%a;%%b;%%Var[i]%%;%%d;>>File_3.txt
        SET /A Counter=+1
    )
)
```

The second loop doesn't seem to work. How can I use my Array's values, knowing that my Array is not static?

Comment: `%Counter%` does not update, you need to apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so use `!Counter!`. But why not using `for /L %%I in (1,1,%Counter%) do call echo %%a;%%b;%%Var[%%I]%%;%%d>>File_3.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for an array; just two nested `for /f` loops:

```
@echo off
(for /f %%x in (file_1.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (file_2.txt) do (
    echo %%a;%%b;%%x;%%d
  )
))>file_3.txt
```

Output:

```
A1;A2;X;A4
B1;B2;X;B4
A1;A2;Y;A4
B1;B2;Y;B4
A1;A2;Z;A4
B1;B2;Z;B4
```

or

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (file_2.txt) do (
  for /f %%x in (file_1.txt) do (
    echo %%a;%%b;%%x;%%d
  )
))>file_3.txt
```

output:

```
A1;A2;X;A4
A1;A2;Y;A4
A1;A2;Z;A4
B1;B2;X;B4
B1;B2;Y;B4
B1;B2;Z;B4
```

depending how you want it sorted.